# url path is matching the wrong view in drf viewsets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django beginner here,

I have two similar endpoints as shown below, they differ in their url_path of the action decorator and the request parameters `requester_id` and `approval id`

**The problem**

both `/workflow_approvals/{requester_id}/` and `/workflow_approvals/{approval_id}/` are routing to the requester method view(the first below)

```
    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False, serializer_class=WorkflowRequesterActivitySerializer, url_path='(?P<requester_id>[^/.]+)')
    def requester_activities(self, request, requester_id, pk=None):
        try:
            approval = WorkflowApproval.objects.filter(requester=requester_id).first()
            if approval is None:
                return Response({'success': False, 'errors': 'No workflow for specified requester'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            activities = WorkflowActivity.objects.filter(
                workflowapproval=approval
            )
            serializer = self.get_serializer(activities, many=True)
            return Response({'success': True, 'data': {'total_count': activities.count(), 'activities': serializer.data}}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'success': False, 'errors': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

```
    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False, serializer_class=WorkflowActivitySerializer, url_path='(?P<approval_id>\w+)',)
    def approval_activities(self, request, approval_id, pk=None):
        try:
            approval = WorkflowApproval.objects.filter(id=approval_id).first()
            if approval is None:
                return Response({'success': False, 'errors': 'Workflow Approval does not exist'},
                                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            activities = WorkflowActivity.objects.filter(
                workflowapproval=approval)
            serializer = self.get_serializer(activities, many=True)
            return Response({'success': True, 'data': {'total_count': activities.count(), 'activities': serializer.data}}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'success': False, 'errors': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

my `urls.py` file looks like this

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


from .views import WorkflowApprovalsViewset


app_name = "workflow_approvals"

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register("", WorkflowApprovalsViewset)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't have a way of differentiating `/workflow_approvals/{requester_id}/` and `/workflow_approvals/{approval_id}/`, since the regex pattern for `(?P<requester_id>[^/.]+)` matches both. So when you make the request with either a `requester_id` or `approval_id`, it'll always end up routing to the former.

You will need instead differentiate the `url_path`s somehow so they don't collide. For instance, including an extra string in the path, like matching `url_path='requester/(?P<requester_id>[^/.]+)')` and `url_path='approval/(?P<approval_id>\w+)')`. (You may want to check out the `Routing for extra actions` [example in the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions).)

But possibly better yet, since it seems you're trying to *filter* your list results based on parameters, I'd recommend checking out the [Filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#generic-filtering) options in Django Rest Framework. You could do something like:

```py
class WorkflowApprovalsViewset(...):
    filterset_fields = ("id", "requester_id",)
    filter_backends = [django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]
```

and then be able to query via the standard list route, with query params like `?id=123` or `?requester_id=42`.

Answer (score 0):

set up different url path in urls.py file for each endpoint